# How update dataset with datagrid view C#

Tags: datagridview, dataset

I am a beginner and I have this problem. How can I can update a dataset with datagridview?

I am binding dataset in datagrid. 
Edit datagrid.
At finish I want to update the dataset with datagridview.

I am using Winforms.

Example: I bind dataset in datagridview.

```
 dataGridViewCustomers.DataSource =
_ds.Tables[0];

 //edit datagridview

 //on this place I want update dataset with datagrid view
```

Comment: What are you using - Winforms? Webforms? WPF? Silverlight? Something else altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
this.Validate();
this.yourBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.yourtableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.yourDataSet);
```

I hope this what you need.

Comment: I am confuse, any example with SqlDataAdapter. How can I use TableManager?